# Search mySQL using MATCH AGAINST: supplied argument is not a valid MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL database called "clients" and displayed like this:

```
FNAME | LNAME | TEL | MAIL | USER | ID
```

Now using this small code I want to search that base for `aaaa` (will be dynamic later on):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE MATCH(LNAME, FNAME, TEL, MAIL) AGAINST('aaaa')";

        $rest = MySQL_query($sql);

        while($row = MySQL_fetch_array($rest)) {

            echo "<tr><td>{$sql['LNAME']}</td>";

            echo "<td>{$sql['FNAME']}</td>";

            echo "<td>{$sql['TEL']}</td>";

            echo "<td>{$sql['MAIL']}</td></tr>";

        }
```

But all I get is `Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /mnt/sites/xxxxxxxx/search.php on line 31`

line 31 being: `while($row = MySQL_fetch_array($rest)) {`

I've tried a 1000 combinations but nothing seems to do the trick. What am I doing wrong?!

Thank you for your help

EDIT: ok I've now added FULLTEXT to my table. I now get no error but the thing is I still get no result. Does this code search all fields and looks if "aaaa" is in all four of them of any of them???

EDIT 2:

changed $sql to $row in the last part of the code. Seems to work...

Edit 3: but only if I `MATCH(LNAME)` (or another one). Not when I add them all.

Comment: note, this is just to get things working. I plan to add security measures later.

Comment: check the output of mysql_error() to see what the actual SQL error is.

Comment: Could you try `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` to see if there's an error occurring on the mysql side?

Comment: Your result is probably returning `false`, meaning that you are supplying a boolean to the function call. Try running `SELECT * FROM clients` to make sure you are at least getting one result.

Comment: Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list... seems to be something basic, let me google that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try either of the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ',LNAME, FNAME, TEL, MAIL) LIKE '%aaaa%'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ',LNAME, FNAME, TEL, MAIL) regexp '.*aaaa+.*'";
```

Comment: First one seems to work :). However when I replace aaaa with my variable $c nothing returns... (c returns "aaaa" for example"). Tried to add it using different combinations but nothing seems to work. Any suggestion?

Comment: if your aaaa is actually more than one word such as "apple pie" you need to type '%apple%pie%' or '.*apple+.*pie+.*' For a better reply, show an example of what aaaa actually is.